# use the stage variable in serverless.yml at handler.js

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless

I'd like to use the variable stage in `handler.js`

**serverless.yml**

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  region: ap-northeast-2
  stage: ${opt:stage, "dev"}
...
```

**handler.js**

```
export const hello = () => {
  // I'd like to use the stage in here,
  const isDev = stage === 'dev';
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: {
      message: `isDev ${isDev}`
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your method of integration is "Lambda Proxy Integration", You should be able to access stage via `event.requestContext.stage`.

```
export const hello = (event) => {
  // I'd like to use the stage in here,
  console.log('stage is: ', event.context.stage)
  const isDev = stage === 'dev';
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: {
      message: `isDev ${isDev}`
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't find `event.context.stage` but I've just got `event.requestContext.stage`

Comment: I've just found another answer that is using `process.env` but I think yours better.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `--stage` variable by adding it as an environment variable and referencing the provider.stage in the yaml, like so.

```
functions:
  yourFunc:
    handler: yourFunc.run
    environment:
      STAGE: ${self:provider.stage}
```

and then reference in your code (if javascript like below)

```
const STAGE = process.env.STAGE
```